# SPMinuteSchedule - can it run longer than 1 minute?

Tags: custom-timer-job

I created Timer Job, and create definition on Feature Activated. I have question about schedule.

If I use Minute Schedule like this:

```
SPMinuteSchedule schedule = new SPMinuteSchedule();
schedule.BeginSecond = 0;
schedule.EndSecond = 59;
```

does that mean, that schedule always starts on 0th second and stops at 59th second of the same minute? What if I have operation, that needs more than 1 minute to finish? Will it be terminated? And if yes, how can I extend running time to eg. 5 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc406686.aspx) post have details. The info extract from the Post

> Notice how the schedule is set for the timer job. The
>   SPMinuteSchedule.BeginSecond property and the
>   SPMinuteSchedule.EndSecond property specify a start window of
>   execution. The SharePoint Timer service starts the timer job at a
>   random time between the BeginSecond property and the EndSecond
>   property. This aspect of the timer service is designed for expensive
>   jobs that execute on all servers in the farm. If all the jobs started
>   at the same time, it could place an unwanted heavy load on the farm.
>   The randomization helps spread the load out across the farm.

So it not terminate the job. It starts between this time span from 0 to 59
 in your case.

Answer (score 1):

No, the schedule starts between 0 seconds and 59 seconds into the schedule and runs until it's finished. This is already answered here:

[TimerJob development, what does the EndSecond property of a SPMinuteSchedule mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132288/timerjob-development-what-does-the-endsecond-property-of-a-spminuteschedule-mea)